# Stop Socket Thread for specific IP Address in Java Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I'm setting up a server software to accept multiple connection from ESP32 board. During testing, the server able to receive multiple connections and multiple message in 100ms without stuck. However, the problem now is the server cannot detect an offline disconnect from the ESP32. I need to stop specific thread for the stop connection because when the board is disconnected, it will try to reconnect again. A new thread is open for the new connection but the old thread is still running.

The connected clients will be listed in a JTable in Server side. I have tried to use Thread.interrup() but it's not working because the code is made to waiting receive something from client to start connection.

Below is the code to remove same IP Address to avoid redundant connection because I'm using fix IP Address and also the interrupt thread.
How do I stop the running thread of remove IP Address because of disconnection?? To get successful interrupt thread do I need to stop readLine() in run()? Below is a code snippet in ClientHandler and the run() where it will wait for data/message from client to connect.

```
socket = clientSocket;

    //Get client IP Address
      clientIP = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();

      Socket socket1;               
      for(int i = 0; i < clientSockets.size(); i++) {
        socket1 = clientSockets.get(i);
                    if(socket1.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().equals(clientIP)) {
                tableModel.removeRow(i);
                    clientSockets.remove(socket1);
                    JTextArea.append(clientIP + " - Disconnected.");

                JTextArea.append("1. Before interrupt--------");
            for(Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) 
               {
            JTextArea.append(t.getName());
            }
        JTextArea.append("--------");


        for(Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) 
        {
          if(t.getId() == threads.get(i).getId()) 
           {
            threads.remove(i);
                t.interrupt();
            break;
              }
           }

        JTextArea.append("2. After interrupt--------");
        for(Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) 
        {
           JTextArea.append(t.getName());
        }
           JTextArea.append("--------");
     }
}


run(){
while ((message = netin.readLine())!=null)// Need to stop the readLine() here to interrupt the thread if not cannot stop it.
try {                   

     String[] data = message.split("&");

      Vector<Object> tableRow = new Vector<Object>();

      if(data[0].equals("connection")) {
      msg1= data[1];
      msg2= data[2];
      msg3= data[3];

      tableRow.add(clientIPAddress);
      tableRow.add(msg1);
      tableRow.add(msg2);
      tableRow.add(msg3);
      // Add a client row into the table
      tableModel.addRow(tableRow);
}
       JTextArea.append("Stop Thread.");

      } catch (Exception ex) {
      JTextArea.append("Run Exception:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "-" + ex);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried closing the socket? Note - Swing *only* allows you to make change to its component from the UI thread. Making changes from other threads may seem to work, most or some of the time, but actually you are breaking the data model because of multi-threaded race conditions. Use EventQueue.invokeLater or invokeAndWait to ensure that you are on the UI thread when you are making changes.

Comment: Better still, shutdown the socket for input. That will cause the receiving thread to see end of stream, which should cause it to close the socket and exit. If it wants to reconnect, set a `boolean` first that will prevent it from looping to a reconnect point.

Comment: If I shutdown the socket then other clients cannot send anything to the server or try to reconnect. This server is always running with more than 20 devices keep connect and disconnect. The UI part has no problem. It can remove the row of the disconnect IP address but when I see at the debugging the thread of the removed row is still running. Is this problem related to UI thread? I thought it's socket thread issue

Comment: Do you control the thread code? You may need to explicitly check Thread.interrupted() (eg `if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException()`) inside your loops in the thread's code.

Comment: @Ryan I tried using thread.interrupted() and catch InterruptedException() but it's not working. the thread is still running without stopping even after 15 min

Comment: @umika1150 in general there is no safe way to stop an uncooperative thread. Either the thread's code needs to change to make it stoppable, or you can use Thread.stop(), which is deprecated because it isn't safe (read the docs before using it.)

Comment: Before this I tried this method of server send back the received message to the client and catch IOException but I had to remove that method because the load to the client is too much that it hangs and disconnect the client from server at certain time interval. When I remove the part where server stop sending and add the interrupt, it won't work. I don't understand

Comment: @umika1150 Impossible. If you shutdown that client's socket it cannot possibly affect the other clients in any way.

Comment: It may help to read this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-stop

Comment: "If I shutdown the socket then other clients cannot send anything to the server" - why? each client has its own socket so closing or shutting down the socket of one client has no impact on the other clients.

Comment: @user207421 okay I'll try this. Sorry I misreading it and thought to shut down the server socket.

Comment: @Ryan Your citation has nothing to say about interrupting a thread that is blocked in a read.